# With word2vec from 2 or more texts, find which text have more similar words

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, word2vec

Given two or more different texts, and using Word2Vec, is it possible to determine a ranking of which of the texts have more similarity between words?

Is it possible to make this kind of comparison?

```
model_text1 = Word2Vec(sentences1, size=100, window=1, sg=1, hs=1)
model_text2 = Word2Vec(sentences2, size=100, window=1, sg=1, hs=1)
```

Is it possible to compare those 2 objects (model_text1 and model_text2) and find which one of them have more similarity?

Comment: Have more similarity to what target? (Are you comparing many texts against each model?) And for what ultimate purpose, with what kinds of texts? (There are many shades of possibility to 'similarity' and meaningful responses will be different if the text is a fragment of keywords, or an essay, or a book, or some other synthetic text.)

Comment: (Separately, by enabling `hs=1` without disabling the default `negative=5`, your `WOrd2Vec` model will train both modes in a simultaneous, interleaved fashion - which is probably not what you want.)

Comment: @gojomo My idea is not to find the similarity to a specific target, I would like to compare two texts to see where there is more similarity between their words. Do I have more similar words in text 1 or in text2.

Comment: A word2vec model sis typically trained on many, many texts - ideally many millions of word usage examples. So you wouldn't want to train one model with `text1` and another model with `text2` where those are typical texts. (Even if they're books, that's smallish. Maybe if each training-set was many books, like an encyclopedia.) So it'd be more common with regard to word2vec to use al the texts you have to train one model, but use other kinds of text-comparison or classification to then decide which pairs of texts are more similar to each other, or to other groups of texts.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Did you get poor results with some simpler approach – like just counting the number of shared words between texts – and what made you consider word2vec-based approaches? And for what ultimate purpose, with what kinds of texts?